# Потеря фокуса cordova

Tags: phonegap, cordova

Помогите. Делаю приложение на cordova. Есть такая проблема: когда нажимаю на поле ввода - показывается клавиатура, и когда нажимаю на кнопку - фокус теряется, клавиатура прячется и экран на секунду делится пополам. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<div data-role="page" id="chat">

<div class="page_one_user" id="bodyChat">

</div>

<div class="footer_button yelow" style="height:50px" id="poleSend">  
    <input type="text" id="textChat" maxlength="255">  
    <a href="#" class="send" id="sendChat">SEND</a>  
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите код, штатных телепатов забрали в нацгвардию.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем за интерес, решил сам. Надо было просто  для `<div data-role="page" id="chat">` задать вместо `fixed` -> `absolute`.